# link back to form visited before

Tags: python, html, post, get, web.py

I am working through Learn Python The Hard Way, and I am currently working through exercise 51. In it, the student is asked to add in file *templates/index.html* a link *back* so that we can keep filling out the form and seeing the results. My code is as follows:

```
/bin
    app.py
/static
/templates
    hello_form.html
    index.html
/tests
```

app.py is written as follows:

```
import web

urls = (
    '/hello', 'Index'
    )

app = web.application(urls, globals())

render = web.template.render('templates/', base="layout")

class Index(object):
    def GET(self):
        return render.hello_form()

    def POST(self):
        form = web.input(name="Nobody", greet="Hello")
        greeting = "%s, %s" % (form.greet, form.name)
        return render.index(greeting = greeting)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

index.html written as follows:

```
$def with (greeting)

$if greeting:
    I just wanted to say <em style="color: green; font-size: 2em;">$greeting</em>
$else:
    <em>Hello</em>, world!
```

hello_form.html written as follows:

```
<h1>Fill out this form</h1>

<form action="/hello" method="POST">
    A Greeting: <input type="text" name="greet">
    <br/>
    Your Name: <input type="text" name="name">
    <br/>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

This *link back* is button on the form, isn't it?
How to add handler for this button?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added these few lines in index.html and it worked.

```
    <form> 
        <input type="button" value="Back" onclick="history.back()">          
    </form>
```

For details, visit https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000317.htm

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with just basic html.  Something like the following:

```
<form method="get" action="/page2">
  <button type="submit">Continue</button>
</form>
```

Should do the job.

Comment: you may don't understand, need that when I press button in index.html and then I go back to first form and this form has text, that I had typed before. And it is not clear how to send or save previous input

Answer (score 1):

Enter this before the last body tag:

```
<a href = "http://localhost:8080/hello">Link to Hello</a>
```

This way it'll just bring you back to the form page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="/hello" method="GET">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

put these code inside the `<body> </body>`

Comment: You probably need to clarify your answer.  For example the original question does not show the body tags of the hello_form and so it mught be confusing to the OP